# Strange behavior of php shell_exec on VPS

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a VPS on inmotion and I'm getting very strange result when using `shell_exec` on a php script. When using local machine server, the script works properly.

test.php:

```
<?php

    if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {

        // When running local -- path changed for example
        echo shell_exec("php /Users/username/test2.php arg1 arg2 arg3");

        // When running on the VPS -- path changed for example
        echo shell_exec("php /home/servername/public_html/site/test2.php arg1 arg2 arg3");

    }

?>
<form id="formranking" name="formranking" method="post" action=<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>
    <input type="text" name="regName" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
Create your second page, call it get_reg.php:
<span>testing shell_exec</span>
```

test2.php

```
<?php

    var_dump($argv);

?>
```

This is what I'm getting running on my local machine:

[image]

This is what I'm getting running on VPS:

[image]

Any tip?

> **UPDATE**

`PHP Safe Mode` is not enable and `register_argc_argv` is set. I run the code below to check:

```
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){ echo ('safe mode is on'); }else{ echo ('its not'); } 
echo '<br>'; 
if(ini_get("register_argc_argv")) { echo "It's set! :)"; } else { echo "It isn't set! :("; }
```

Logs doesn't show anything anomalous

Comment: Is it possible your server is running with register_argc_argv disabled or safe mode enabled? I'd check error logs first and make sure there is nothing anomalous being reported.